# ps --filter does not work with -H

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I need to get a list of containers running using particular Image Id. But, 
`--filter ancestor={Image Id}` does not work with `-H` option. 
for ex.  `$ docker -H {Host_ip}:{port_no} ps --filter ancestor={Image Id}`
Neither it shows any error nor shows the correct result. Everytime output shows a list all the containers only.

Docker Version: 1.10.2

Answer (score 1):

1. Run "docker ps" command on the target host to confirm the problem
2. Remember to use "-a" option. Maybe the container is not running...

I successfully run "docker ps" wit -H and "--filter ancestor={image-id}" successfully using docker 1.10.3

```
docker -H 192.168.59.2:4000 ps -a --filter ancestor=f71a93076f3f
```